# Bind data with nested object using Knockout MVC in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm using `Knockout MVC` from [here](http://knockoutmvc.com/) to integrate knockout to my website, but I have a problem. If my model contains another object, the binding will be unsuccessful. For example, here is my model:

```
public class HelloWorldModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Computed]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }

    public ProductModel ProductModel { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my `ProductModel`

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

These models are just for testing, so they're very simple. Here is my view to display:

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model MyStore.UI.Models.HelloWorldModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HelloWorld";
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

<p>
    Name: @ko.Html.TextBox(x => x.ProductModel.Name)
</p>
<p>
    Price: @ko.Html.TextBox(x => x.ProductModel.Price)
</p>
<h2>
    Product @ko.Html.Span(x => x.ProductModel.Name), @ko.Html.Span(x => x.ProductModel.Price)
</h2>

<p>First name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstName)</p>
<p>Last name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.LastName)</p>
<h2>Hello, @ko.Html.Span(m => m.FullName)!</h2>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

But it's failed. Nothing appeared. `<input/>` is blank, so does the `<span>`. What's the wrong thing here? I guess something's wrong at binding context. Please help me. Thank you so much.

**Editted! Here is part of the auto-generated HTML:**

The binding:

```
Name: <input data-bind="value : ProductModel().Name" />
```

The view model:

```
var viewModelJs = {"FirstName":"AAA","LastName":"BBB","FullName":"AAA BBB","ProductModel":{"Id":0,"Name":"Coca Cola","Price":123.0,"CategoryId":0,"IsActive":false}};
```

Comment: Just a tip, Knockout MVC is a huge anti pattern. Dont do it. Its the bastard child of Web Forms. We have worked so hard to get away from Web forms and KO MVC brings us back

Comment: But now, I'm in a case that I have to use it :(

Comment: This is a known and sadly open of issue of the Knockout MVC library see: [data-bind attribute for Nested object is invalid](https://github.com/AndreyAkinshin/knockout-mvc/issues/12) as a workaround use can use the with binding: `@using (var subModel = ko.With(m => m.ProductModel))
       { @subModel.Html.TextBox(x => ko.Model..Name)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've found the solution. Great! Let's me answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `nemesv`'s comment, I've found the solution. To access the nested object, here is `Product`, we use `With` binding. Here is the code for the view:

```
@using (var product = ko.With(x => x.ProductModel))
{
    <p>
        Name: @product.Html.TextBox(x => x.Name)
    </p>
    <p>
        Price: @product.Html.TextBox(x => x.Price)
    </p>
    <h2>
        Product @product.Html.Span(x => x.Name), @product.Html.Span(x => x.Price)
    </h2>
}

<p>First name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.FirstName)</p>
<p>Last name: @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.LastName)</p>
<h2>Hello, @ko.Html.Span(m => m.FullName)!</h2>
```